# Javascript ajax result not able to split

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using javascript. The following is object from jax response,

```
  {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\nsuccess","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

and my code is,

```
complete: function(data)
{
   //console.log(data);
   var result_act = JSON.stringify(data);
   alert(result_act);//returning above object
   var resp = result_act.responseText;//Returning undefined
 }
```

now i want to get the responseText from this object. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `JSON.stringify` you need `JSON.parse`

`parse` will parse the incoming *JSON* string into appropriate *Javascript* object. `stringify` is the opposite action - Javascript object into *JSON* valid string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// When your server response comes with full qualified parsed JSON, it may access without any parsing.

    var data, resp;
    data = {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\nsuccess","status":200,"statusText":"OK"};
    resp = data.responseText;
    console.log("Response as JSON object >",resp);

// When your server response comes with JSON as string, then you require to first parse then you may allows to access.

    data = '{\"readyState\":4,\"responseText\":\"\\r\\nsuccess\",\"status\":200,\"statusText\":\"OK\"}';
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    resp = data.responseText;
    console.log("Response after parsing JSON >",resp);
```